# Proof involving Differential Equations's solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Here is the question :

> If $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the solutions of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} +Py = Q$, where P & Q are functions of $x$ alone, and $y_2=y_1z $, then prove that $$z=1+ae^{-\int \frac{Q}{y_1}\,dx} $$,  'a' being an arbitrary constant.

I have been at this for hours now, what I tried is:

1. I tried to differentiate the relation $y_2 = y_1 z$ and relate the individual equations of $y_1$ and $y_2$ .

2.Dividing equations of $y_1$ and $y_2$  to get some relation between the constants of integration in both case

But I haven't been able to reach anything conclusive.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Moo sure...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of

$$\tag 1 \dfrac{dy}{dx} +Py = Q$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are functions of $x$ alone, and $y_2=y_1z$, and asked to prove that

$$z=1+ae^{-\int \frac{Q}{y_1}\,dx} $$

where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

Given $y_2 = y_1 z$, taking the derivative $\tag 2 y_2' = y_1' z + y_1 z'$

Since $y_2$ is a solution to $(1)$, we have

$$y_2' + P y_2 = Q$$

Substituting

$$y_1' z + y_1 z' + P y_1 z = Q$$

Simplifying

$$z(y_1' + Py _1) + y_1 z' = Q$$

Using $(1)$ for the expression in parenthesis, this reduces to

$$z Q + y_1 z' = Q$$

This is a [*Separable Equation*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx)

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{z-1}~dz = \int -\dfrac{Q}{y_1}~dx$$

Integrating

$$\ln(z-1) = c + \int -\dfrac{Q}{y_1}~dx$$

Solving for $z$

$$z = 1 + a e^{-\int \frac{Q}{y_1}~dx}$$